# ViewDidLoad runs before AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets executed!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, delegates

i am experiencing a strange problem where the Method "ViewDidLoad" runs before the  AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets executed!
Cause I only check if a database exists in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" my app crashes if the database isnt there. after poking around for a couple of hours I am tired of doing so and call for HEEEEELP! 
If you please could be so kind and point me into the right direction what's likely to be wrong with my project. I cant figure it out (aaarggh!)

Thank you!

Best regards
Tom

Comment: How are you checking for the existence of the db. Showing the code would help.

Comment: Post some code of appDidFinishLaunching and if database is not created, then create it.

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions does not run if you come from the background, just in case you didn't know that.

Comment: I am happy to post some code, but since appDidFinishLaunching never gets executed, I doubt it will shed light on the problem since the problem lies somewhere else....

Answer (score 3):

viewDidLoad may run on ViewControllers loaded from NIBs as these are loaded before the call to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after looking in the code in more detail, I have found out that inside `awakeFromNib` of a xViewController, i am initing another yViewController. So the `viewDidLoad` of yViewController runs before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Basically, the initial VC's `awakeFromNib` is called before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. You might have something similar of a setup. Look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If your database files do not load fast enough; override your AppDelegate's init():

```
override init() {
    if filesExistBool == false {
        addDBFiles()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you.

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you decide what views to load. The app will not randomly load views without you telling it to do so. Did you put a breakpoint first in `viewDidLoad` and one first in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or do you just assume that `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` didn't get executed because it's not working.

Comment: it will finally get to "application:didFinishWithOptions" if the app doenst crash on the first hand, but after my code breaks in the viewcontrollers "viewDidLoad" because no database was copied, it wont execute "application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" (where the copying of the database happens)

Comment: I am just puzzled by the fact that "application:didFinishWithOptions" doesnt run in the right order (as first) any more and I am interested how you change it to the right order again....