# viewControllers initialized *before* application didFinishLaunching

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I've found a case where some of my view controllers' initWithCoder methods are invoked *before* the application didFinishLaunching method in the application delegate. (I've confirmed this by setting breakpoints and looking at the sequence of invocations)

I'm using a storyboard. A UITabBarController is the initial view controller.  Part of the problem is that the storyboard creates objects in an unknown order;  perhaps it's creating the view controllers before the app is done launching.

In any case, the problem is that I'm registering initial user defaults.  This must happen before any piece of the program looks at them.  So, I'm trying to find the spot where the registering code will be guaranteed to execute first.

Is there any such place?

Note:
This thread discusses it a little, but there isn't really a conclusion...

[ViewDidLoad runs before AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets executed!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139667/viewdidload-runs-before-appdelegate-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-gets-executed?rq=1)

Comment: I see that your are new to StackOverFlow, and just so you know - it helps people who help you if you select their answer by tapping on the checkmark - and if you really like the answer you can tap on the up arrow under "Answer". This is all voluntary, and nothing happens if you don't do this. But you get a rating of "accepted", that is what percentage of questions you selected an answer, and the higher this number is the more people will help you in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard means of initializing user defaults is in a "+(void)initialize" method in your app delegate:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    if(self == [MyAppDelegate class]) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is guaranteed to run before any delegate method gets messaged.

PS: I instantiate a whole bunch of viewControllers in my didLaunch method before returning from that method.

Comment: Is this run before the root view controller is loaded?

Comment: Yes - initialize is called by the runtime before any instance ever gets a message. So it must be sent before applicationDidLaunch... and friends.

Answer (score 0):

This is natural (and also one of the reasons why using InterfaceBuilder sucks). In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: you generally rely upon the main window and main view controller having already been created from their corresponding NIB/XIB files. Two solutions:

One (preferred): instantiate stuff manually in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. You can thus control the execution order of any initialization.

Two: use `__attribute__((constructor(XXX)))` functions - they're guaranteed to be called before main, and the lower the XXX number the earlier the particular constructor function is called. This method is, however, not advisable, because it isn't standard C (only a compiler extension), and it also can easily get very confusing.